# Use of unresolved identifiers

Tags: swift, xcode7

Guys can you please help with this error. i am working with `CoreData`. I have an error in this code. Specifically in the last part of code (return items). the error description tells use of unresolved identifier 'items'

```
class func fetchEntities(className:NSString, withPredicate predicate:NSPredicate?, managedObjectContext:NSManagedObjectContext)->NSArray{
    let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
    let entetyDescription:NSEntityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName(className as! String, inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)!

    fetchRequest.entity = entetyDescription

    if predicate != nil{
        fetchRequest.predicate = predicate!
    }

    fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false


    do{
       let items = try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)

    } catch {

        print("error")

    }
    return items
}
```

the specific code with error is

return items

Answer (score 1):

You initialized item in the do {} block so the items in the function do not know what is the item variable , so you should initialize item variable in the beginning of the function so :-

```
class func fetchEntities(className:NSString, withPredicate predicate:NSPredicate?, managedObjectContext:NSManagedObjectContext)->NSArray{
let items: NSArray!
let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
let entetyDescription:NSEntityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName(className as! String, inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)!

fetchRequest.entity = entetyDescription

if predicate != nil{
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate!
}

fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false


do{
   items = try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)

} catch {

    print("error")

}
return items
}
```

Comment: i already do that and i got an error. Constant 'items' used before being initialized

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
do{
   let items = try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)

}
```

creates a new scope. Outside of that scope `items` is not accessible.